# Answer flagged as "not an answer" still exists (was not removed)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags, moderation, not-an-answer

Some number of days ago I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302279/877472) which I felt was a very poor attempt to answer the question.

So I flagged it as "not an answer", and a while later my flag was marked as "helpful". However, I just noticed today that the answer still seems to exist, as I had thought it would get deleted. I've only been actively flagging posts for the past few months, and thus far have a decent flag rating, however I am interested in learning more about how moderator decisions are made in situations like this. Why would an answer like this not be removed?

As always, please let me know if I can provide additional info or correct this question. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest that you flag it again using a custom flag. You can only flag as "not an answer" once, but you can custom flag as many times as you like.

Comment: @gparyani Good point, I was wondering that as well; whether it would be a good idea to do something like that. And thanks for the link, not sure how I missed that one. According to the accepted answer, the second point `Your flag was borderline, and the moderator felt it wasn't a bad enough post to act on it, but wanted to let you know you weren't exactly wrong.` might fit this situation, but I'm still quite surprised that the moderator would feel that way, as the poster's answer almost feels like spam or trolling in the way its worded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like another case of an answer having been automatically deleted by review (hence your flag being marked as "helpful"), and then manually undeleted by its author. You can see this in its [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19302279/revisions) — notice that there's no deletion entry *before* the undeletion notice.

I've deleted the answer myself now, which the author won't be able to reverse. There was no moderator involvement prior to this. I have a feeling review deletions are bugged and that a user shouldn't be able to reverse a review deletion by themselves, but I'm not sure if any reports exist on meta yet to effect some sort of change.

Comment: Was my "possible duplicate" a viable duplicate? (I posted another question that got marked as a duplicate of the target.)

Comment: So, in general, the author's post cannot be undeleted if deleted by a moderator?

Comment: @Jamal: The author cannot undelete it on their own - they'll have to flag. It can still be undeleted by another moderator.

Comment: @gparyani: Not sure, we'll let the rest of the community decide. This does highlight a certain problem that I think needs fixing though.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Understood.

Comment: Ah ha, very interesting. I didn't realize the author could undelete their own post in that situation (review deletion). Very strange to me, though, that the author thought it was a good post to begin with, enough to make the effort to undelete it. I don't see the revision history; I get a "page not found". I'm assuming it is because the answer was removed. Either way, its toast. Thanks for removing it.